# Exceptional divisor as projectivization of the tangent space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, blowup

Let $X\subseteq \mathbb{P}^n$ be a projective variety, and let $p\in X$. I define the blow up of $X$ at $p$ as the closure $\Gamma$ in $X\times \mathbb{P}^{n-1}$ of the graph of the projection $\phi$ from $p$.

We have a projection $\pi:\Gamma\to X$. Is it true that $\pi^{-1}(p)=(p, \phi(T_pX))$?

I asked myself this question in order to motivate the fact that the exceptional divisor is often described as $\mathbb{P}(T_pX)$.

Comment: As it is a local statement did you try to prove it for the blow-up of $W$ at $p$ in $V$ where $V$ is a vector space and $W \subset V$ a subspace? I believe this case should be easy, and if you can do it you can probably figure out how to do it for a general $X \subset \Bbb P^n$.

Comment: The problem with that is that I am not working over $\mathbb{C}$, so that it is not necessarily true that $X\cong \mathbb{A}^n$.

Comment: Ok, but I still think that the closure of affine tangent space is the projective tangent space anyways, and fiber are closed so it should be enough to prove it for blow-up of affine variety.

Comment: Yes it is enough to show it for an affine variety, but that I cannot do :)